# Change "Publisher's website" on Microsoft and/or Azure AD Graph consent screen

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office-app

When sending my user to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize` endpoint during an oAuth flow, they are presented with the consent page. On this consent page, when they authorize the application, it displays the Office 365 tenant in which my Application is registered in. I'd like for this to show my organizations website. Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible today but the change will apply to the consent screen for all apps in that tenant. If your organization's website is already registered as a custom domain of the tenant, it's as simple as marking that domain as primary. If it is not, you'll first need to add it as a custom domain and then mark it as primary. To manage your custom domain names, follow the steps outlined in [this doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-domains-manage-azure-portal)

Comment: the domain is verified, however, it is federated. you cannot make federated domains primary. this is the only way?

Comment: This worked... but it took a while before the changes were published.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation, and noticed that now we can change each application's "Publisher" individually. Please check the following documents:

- [How to: Configure an application's publisher domain (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain)